# deflate and inflate (zlib.h) in C

Tags: c, compression, zlib, deflate

I am trying to implement the zlib.h deflate and inflate functions to compress and decompress a char array (not a file).

I would like to know if the following syntax is correct ? Am I missing something or defined something incorrectly ?

```c
char a[50] = "Hello World!";
char b[50];
char c[50];

// deflate
// zlib struct
z_stream defstream;
defstream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
defstream.zfree = Z_NULL;
defstream.opaque = Z_NULL;
defstream.avail_in = (uInt)sizeof(a); // size of input
defstream.next_in = (Bytef *)a; // input char array
defstream.avail_out = (uInt)sizeof(b); // size of output
defstream.next_out = (Bytef *)b; // output char array

deflateInit(&defstream, Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION);
deflate(&defstream, Z_FINISH);
deflateEnd(&defstream);

printf("Deflate:\n%lu\n%s\n", strlen(b), b);

// inflate
// zlib struct
z_stream infstream;
infstream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
infstream.zfree = Z_NULL;
infstream.opaque = Z_NULL;
infstream.avail_in = (uInt)sizeof(b); // size of input
infstream.next_in = (Bytef *)b; // input char array
infstream.avail_out = (uInt)sizeof(c); // size of output
infstream.next_out = (Bytef *)c; // output char array

inflateInit(&infstream);
inflate(&infstream, Z_NO_FLUSH);
inflateEnd(&infstream);

printf("Inflate:\n%lu\n%s\n", strlen(c), c);
```

Comment: Are you asking because it isn't working? Are you getting some sort of error message?

Comment: @larsks It compiles without warnings but I want to know if the functions and definitions I chose make sense or if I should use others.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks for clarifying your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't printf the deflated output like this.  It's not null terminated.  You can't strlen it either.

Since your input is a string though you probably do want to only pass the content of the string including the null terminator.  So set avail_in to strlen(a) + 1.

You need to examine the next_out and avail_out fields after you call deflate to see how much data was written to the output buffer.

See documentation [here](http://zlib.net/manual.html#Basic) under the deflate call.

Here's your modified code.  Note if you're compressing something that is not a string you'll need to change this and also with strings you may compress without the terminating zero and add it back after decompressing.

```
char a[50] = "Hello World!";
char b[50];
char c[50];

// deflate
// zlib struct
z_stream defstream;
defstream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
defstream.zfree = Z_NULL;
defstream.opaque = Z_NULL;
defstream.avail_in = (uInt)strlen(a)+1; // size of input, string + terminator
defstream.next_in = (Bytef *)a; // input char array
defstream.avail_out = (uInt)sizeof(b); // size of output
defstream.next_out = (Bytef *)b; // output char array

deflateInit(&defstream, Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION);
deflate(&defstream, Z_FINISH);
deflateEnd(&defstream);

// This is one way of getting the size of the output
printf("Deflated size is: %lu\n", (char*)defstream.next_out - b);

// inflate
// zlib struct
z_stream infstream;
infstream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
infstream.zfree = Z_NULL;
infstream.opaque = Z_NULL;
infstream.avail_in = (uInt)((char*)defstream.next_out - b); // size of input
infstream.next_in = (Bytef *)b; // input char array
infstream.avail_out = (uInt)sizeof(c); // size of output
infstream.next_out = (Bytef *)c; // output char array

inflateInit(&infstream);
inflate(&infstream, Z_NO_FLUSH);
inflateEnd(&infstream);

printf("Inflate:\n%lu\n%s\n", strlen(c), c);
```

Answer (score 31):

zlib already has a simple inflate/deflate function you can use.

```
char a[50] = "Hello, world!";
char b[50];
char c[50];

uLong ucompSize = strlen(a)+1; // "Hello, world!" + NULL delimiter.
uLong compSize = compressBound(ucompSize);

// Deflate
compress((Bytef *)b, &compSize, (Bytef *)a, ucompSize);

// Inflate
uncompress((Bytef *)c, &ucompSize, (Bytef *)b, compSize);
```

When in doubt, check out the [zlib manual](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html).
My code is crappy, sorry =/

Comment: +1 crappy perhaps, but it points to a mind-numbing solution, which is always preferred. `compress()` and `uncompress()` are about the simplest form you can get, and you present it more than adequately.

Comment: Problem with this utility-method is that you need to somehow know the size of the ucompressed content... :/

Comment: In which case you can use sizeof() on the uncompressed content. It's a basic usage of the compress() and uncompress() methods which is a good start but there are more efficient techniques out there.

Answer (score 3):

The zpipe example (http://zlib.net/zpipe.c) pretty much covers it, just remove the file ops(the f prefixed function), and you replace `in` and `out` with your in-memory buffers, though it may be enough to only replace `in` or keep the buffers as-is depending on you usage. Just note that you will need to make your *out* buffer resizeable to account for decompression of arbitrarily sized data, if you are planning on having unknown sized chunks