# C++ Inflate gzip char array

Tags: c++, gzip, zlib, inflate

I'm attempting to use zlib to uncompress (inflate) some IP packet payload data that is compressed via gzip. However, I'm having some difficultly understanding some of the documentation provided by zlib that covers inflation. I have a char array that my program fills but I can't seem to inflate it with the following code:

```
const u_char payload; /*contains gzip data, 
                      captured prior to this point in the program*/

/*read compressed contents*/
int ret; //return val
z_stream stream;
unsigned char out[MEM_CHUNK]; //output array, MEM_CHUNK defined as 65535

/* allocate inflate state */
stream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
stream.zfree = Z_NULL;
stream.opaque = Z_NULL;
stream.avail_in = size_payload; // size of input
stream.next_in = (Bytef *)payload; // input char array
stream.avail_out = (uInt)sizeof(out); // size of output
stream.next_out = (Bytef *)out; // output char array

ret = inflateInit(&stream);
inflate(&stream, Z_NO_FLUSH);
inflateEnd(&stream);

printf("Inflate: %s\n\n", out);
```

In the [zlib documentation](http://www.zlib.net/zlib_how.html), they have inflate continually called via a do/while loop, checking for the Z_STREAM_END flag. I'm a bit confused here, because it seems they're working from a file while I'm not. Do I need this loop as well, or am I able to provide a char array without looping over inflate?

Any guidance here would really be appreciated. I'm pretty new to both working with compression and C++.

Thanks.

Comment: The most glaring thing i see wrong with this immediately is the cast of `payload`, a `const u_char`, to a `Bytef*` ***pointer*** type. Methinks this is destined for a core-dump. Or was that supposed to be an array or some dynamically allocated data buffer?

Comment: Edit: @WhozCraig my understanding of it is that it is supposed to be a dynamic data array, but I'm not completely sure, I'm working from some [sample code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540259/deflate-and-inflate-zlib-h-in-c) that did that with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are giving `inflate` an appropriate and complete "compressed stream", and there is enough space to output the data, you would only need to call `inflate` once.

Edit: It is not written out as clearly as that in the [zlib documentation](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html), but it does say:

> `inflate` decompresses as much data as possible, and stops when the
>   input buffer becomes empty or the output buffer becomes full. It may
>   introduce some output latency (reading input without producing any
>   output) except when forced to flush.

Of course, for any stream that isn't already "in memory and complete", you want to run it block by block, since that's going to have less total runtime (you can decompress while the data is being received [from network or filesystem pre-fetch caching] for the next block).

Here's the whole function from your example code. I've removed the text components from the page to concentrate the code, and marked sections with letters `// A` , `// B` etc, then marked tried to explain the sections below.

```
int inf(FILE *source, FILE *dest)
{
    int ret;
    unsigned have;
    z_stream strm;
    unsigned char in[CHUNK];     // A
    unsigned char out[CHUNK];

    /* allocate inflate state */
    strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;        // B
    strm.zfree = Z_NULL;
    strm.opaque = Z_NULL;
    strm.avail_in = 0;
    strm.next_in = Z_NULL;
    ret = inflateInit(&strm);    // C
    if (ret != Z_OK)
        return ret;

    /* decompress until deflate stream ends or end of file */
    do {
        strm.avail_in = fread(in, 1, CHUNK, source);     // D
        if (ferror(source)) {
            (void)inflateEnd(&strm);      // E
            return Z_ERRNO;
        }
        if (strm.avail_in == 0)           // F
            break;
        strm.next_in = in;                // G


        /* run inflate() on input until output buffer not full */
        do {
            strm.avail_out = CHUNK;       // H
            strm.next_out = out;

            ret = inflate(&strm, Z_NO_FLUSH);  // I
            assert(ret != Z_STREAM_ERROR);  /* state not clobbered */
            switch (ret) {
            case Z_NEED_DICT:
                ret = Z_DATA_ERROR;     /* and fall through */
            case Z_DATA_ERROR:
            case Z_MEM_ERROR:
                (void)inflateEnd(&strm);
                return ret;
            }

            have = CHUNK - strm.avail_out;     // J
            if (fwrite(out, 1, have, dest) != have || ferror(dest)) {
                (void)inflateEnd(&strm);    
                return Z_ERRNO;
            }

        } while (strm.avail_out == 0);         // K

        /* done when inflate() says it's done */
    } while (ret != Z_STREAM_END);             // L

    /* clean up and return */
    (void)inflateEnd(&strm);
    return ret == Z_STREAM_END ? Z_OK : Z_DATA_ERROR;
}
```

**A**: `in` is the input buffer (we read from a file into this buffer, then pass it to `inflate` a while later. `out` is the output buffer, which is used by `inflate` to store the output data.

**B**: Set up a `z_stream` object called `strm`. This holds various fields, most of which are not important here (thus set to Z_NULL). The important ones are the `avail_in` and `next_in` as well as `avail_out` and `next_out` (which are set later).

**C**: Start inflation process. This sets up some internal data structures and just makes the `inflate` function itself "ready to run".

**D**: Read a "CHUNK" amount of data from file. Store the number of bytes read in `strm.avail_in`, and the actual data goes into `in`.

**E**: If we errored out, finish the `inflate` by calling `inflateEnd`. Job done.

**F**: No data available, we're finished.

**G**: Set where our data is coming from (`next_in` is set to the input buffer, `in`).

**H**: We're now in the loop to inflate things. Here we set the output buffer up: `next_out` and `avail_out` indicate where the output goes and how much space there is, respectively.

**I**: Call `inflate` itself. This will uncompress a portion of the input buffer, until the output is full.

**J**: Calculate how much data is available in this step (`have` is the number of bytes).

**K**: Until we have space left when `inflate` finished - this indicates the output is completed for the data in the `in` buffer, rather than out of space in the out buffer. So time to read some more data from the input file.

**L**: If the error code from the `inflate` call is "happy", go round again.

Now, obviously, if you are reading from a network, and uncompressing into memory, you need to replace the `fread` and `fwrite` with some suitable `read from network` and `memcpy` type calls instead. I can't tell you EXACTLY what those are, since you haven't provided anything to explain where your data comes from - are you calling `recv` or `read` or `WSARecv`, or something else? - and where is it going to?

Comment: I am trying the read the data block by block, should I not be making the z_stream then and be calling inflate() in a different manner?

Comment: Right, so then you should call `inflate` in a loop, giving a new block every time it's "hungry" (that is, it finished the previous block). [obviously, wait for the data to be complete in that block, or it will go badly wrong]. For test purposes, it would make sense to collect ALL the data first, then decompress it, just to simplify the process [and you could also save that data as a file and uncompress it "by hand" to see that you get the same data as you expect]

Comment: Looking in the [zlib documentation](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html#Basic), I see that all calls to inflate() need a z_stream parameter, where I think I'm getting confused is where does this correspond to my input char array?

Comment: I have expanded my answer based on the example code from your link. Since your code contains nothing to indicate how the data arrives at the function, I can't say what you need to do to make it work with your data stream.

Comment: Note that the example code here is copied from [this page](http://zlib.net/zlib_how.html), which has extensive commentary on the usage of zlib.  The pointers and amount of data or space at the input or output pointers respectively are all set or updated in the `z_stream` structure before each call of `inflate()`.