# c++ decompress char * in memory with zlib

Tags: c++, zlib, compression

I've hooked the recv function of a server application and I need to decompress the received char * using zlib, all I can find are examples of decompression to/from File* and modifying the code to fit a Char * just throws out a massive list of errors.

Could someone show me the best way of decompressing a char in memory with zlib?

Heres my recv function :

```
int WINAPI MyRecv(SOCKET socket, char* buffer, int length, int flags)
{
    int returnVal = precv(socket, buffer, length, flags);
    if (strlen(buffer) > 4)
    {
            //decompress buffer with zlib here.
    }
    return returnVal;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [deflate and inflate (zlib.h) in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540259/deflate-and-inflate-zlib-h-in-c)

Comment: Maybe you could trying doing something with the `mmap()` equivalent for windows. Create an empty file, `mmap()` it, `memcpy()` your data, and try running zlib.

Comment: @djf I can't use that method as I don't know the output size.

Comment: Using `strlen` on binary data is a sure sign of problems to come.

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html).  Use the `uncompress()` function.

Comment: For some strange reason, I think this @MarkAdler guy may know what he's talking about.  ;-) ;-) ;-)

Comment: @JoeZ Definitely not. He's obviously a friggin' elitist. Reading the documentation? What a rude blasphemy!