# C/C++: Compressing(gz) data without using temporary file

Tags: c++, c, compression, gzip, zlib

I have some data in an array,

```
uchar *data = "Data to be compressed."; [Some data]
```

I want to compress(**gz**) this data and get output in a buffer.

```
uchar gzData[MAX_LEN];
```

One way to do this is:

```
 1. Creating a `ogzstream` object.
 2. Writing this data into a temporary file
 3. close the temporary file.
 3. Create a `ifstream` object.
 4. Read the temporary file into buffer using ifstream object .
```

But I do not want to use a temporary file for this as it is slowing down the whole process.

Is there any direct method of compressing this data without using any intermediate file ??

Comment: you do realize that what you are creating is a stream and not a file? There is filesystem interaction here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filtering `streambuf` to do this on the fly.  It's pretty easy to do, but Boost::Iostreams has one already done for you.

Comment: I do not know "Boost". :( Can u send me a link to some tutorial/example for the same?

Comment: How about std::stringstream?

Comment: You can start at www.boost.org.  They've got a number of libraries; they tend to be overly generic (and thus overly complicated), but depending on what you're doing, some can be quite useful.

Comment: @FominArseniy `std::stringstream` doesn't support any compression.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Thanks for the suggestions sir. Actually, This is what I was actually trying to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540259/deflate-and-inflate-zlib-h-in-c .