# why zlib deflateInit calling once not working?

Tags: c++, zlib

I am currently writing a function which compress the char array using zlib. Since I want to optimize the performance and speed, I want to only call deflateInit() once and reuse zstream object as I want to avoid re-allocation, de-allocation repeatedly. I have tried below method which just updates input and output buffer in zstream object, but it doesn't give correct output from second iteration of while loop. Below is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <iostream>

#include <string.h> // for strlen

#include <assert.h>

#include <chrono>

#include "zlib.h"

// adapted from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540259/deflate-and-inflate-zlib-h-in-c
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  // original string len = 36
  char a[500] = {};

  for (int i = 0; i < 498; i++) {
    a[i] = 'a';
  }
  a[499] = '\0';

  // placeholder for the compressed (deflated) version of "a"
  char b[500] = {};

  // placeholder for the UNcompressed (inflated) version of "b"
  char c[500] = {};

  printf("Uncompressed size is: %lu\n", strlen(a));
  printf("Uncompressed string is: %s\n", a);

  printf("\n----------\n\n");

  z_stream defstream;
  defstream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
  defstream.zfree = Z_NULL;
  defstream.opaque = Z_NULL;
  deflateInit( & defstream, Z_BEST_COMPRESSION);

  int i = 0;
  while (i < 5) {

    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    // setup "a" as the input and "b" as the compressed output

    // STEP 1.
    // deflate a into b. (that is, compress a into b)

    // zlib struct
    int ret;
    char b[500] = {};

    defstream.avail_in = (uInt) strlen(a) + 1; // size of input, string + terminator
    defstream.next_in = (Bytef * ) a; // input char array
    defstream.avail_out = 500;

    defstream.next_out = (Bytef * ) b;
    ret = deflate( & defstream, Z_FINISH); /* no bad return value */
    std::cout << "ret" << ret << std::endl;
    std::cout << "avail_out" << defstream.avail_out << std::endl;

    assert(ret != Z_STREAM_ERROR); /* state not clobbered */

    // This is one way of getting the size of the output
    printf("Compressed size is: %lu\n", strlen(b));
    printf("Compressed string is: %s\n", b);
    std::cout << "Compressed return value is: " << ret << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Avail out is: " << defstream.avail_out << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Compressed length is: " << defstream.total_out << std::endl;

    printf("\n----------\n\n");
    memset(b, 0, 500);


    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cout << "Timestamp: Total compression took: " <<
      std::chrono::duration_cast < std::chrono::microseconds > (t2 - t1).count() <<
      " microseconds\n";

    i++;
  }
  deflateEnd( & defstream);

  // inflateEnd(&infstream);

  return 0;
}
```

*OUTPUT:*

```
----------

ret1
avail_out35
Compressed size is: 9
Compressed string is: x�KL#
                           0
Compressed return value is: 1
Avail out is: 35
Compressed length is: 15

----------

Timestamp: Total compression took: 103 microseconds
ret-5
avail_out50
Compressed size is: 0
Compressed string is: 
Compressed return value is: -5
Avail out is: 50
Compressed length is: 15

----------

Timestamp: Total compression took: 42 microseconds
ret-5
avail_out50
Compressed size is: 0
Compressed string is: 
Compressed return value is: -5
Avail out is: 50
Compressed length is: 15

----------

Timestamp: Total compression took: 41 microseconds
ret-5
avail_out50
Compressed size is: 0
Compressed string is: 
Compressed return value is: -5
Avail out is: 50
Compressed length is: 15

----------

Timestamp: Total compression took: 41 microseconds
ret-5
avail_out50
Compressed size is: 0
Compressed string is: 
Compressed return value is: -5
Avail out is: 50
Compressed length is: 15

----------

Timestamp: Total compression took: 42 microseconds
```

Here you can see that, I am getting error code -5 (Z_BUF_ERROR) and empty b array from second iteration of while loop. But if I move zlib object declaration and deflateInit() inside while loop, everything works fine. Any explanation?

Answer (score 0):

In the doc of [zlib](https://www.zlib.net/manual.html) they write:

> If the parameter flush is set to Z_FINISH, pending input is processed, pending output is flushed and deflate returns with Z_STREAM_END if there was enough output space. If deflate returns with Z_OK or Z_BUF_ERROR, this function must be called again with Z_FINISH and more output space (updated avail_out) but no more input data, until it returns with Z_STREAM_END or an error. After deflate has returned Z_STREAM_END, the only possible operations on the stream are deflateReset or deflateEnd.

So it needs more buffer, noting you have a buffer of 500 but only say avail is 50, that could be the error else you need some more logic to add more buffer.

Comment: But if my input buffer is of size 500, then ideally compression should not need more that 500 right? Else, whats the use of compression if it needs more size?